# Pass --build-arg to Dockerfile FROM instruction

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

How do I pass `--build-arg` to a *Dockerfile* in order to populate the version of the image?

e.g.

```bash
FROM <custom_Image>:$VERSION
```

Note: the docker build statement is inside a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You use the ARG statement in your Dockerfile like this

```
ARG myversion
FROM nginx:${myversion}
```

Then you can pass it from your build command like this

```
docker build --build-arg myversion=xyzzy .
```

It'll then complain that an 'xyzzy' version of nginx doesn't exist, proving that it's trying to get `nginx:xyzzy`.

It shouldn't matter that the docker build statement is in a bash script.